# How to find lowest count of rows for a value in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `OrderUser`

```
UserName   |  OrderNo
-----------------------
User1      |  1
User1      |  2
User1      |  3
User2      |  4
User2      |  5
```

I need the only the `userID` with min rows, meaning `user2` in this case.

Simple T-Sql statement is required because I will use the code in a `SqlCommand` in C#.

Please help.

Comment: And in the case of ties... return all, first alphabetical by username, one with the lowest orderNumber.... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 UserName, COUNT(*) 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY UserName 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```

Comment: Thnk you so much. but can it be possible to return only the username column without count(*) column by using any subquery or somthing like that.

Comment: You can just leave out `, COUNT(*)`, but mind that you need the count in the last row.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. Its *derived table* (inner `select`)

- summarizes the data by user name
- orders it by `count(*)` in ascending sequence
- then assigns each discrete frequency value a rank (1-N) based on that ordering

The outer `select` then keeps only the row or rows with a rank of 1 (meaning those with the lowest frequency value), ordering them by user name

```
select *
from ( select Rank      = rank() over ( order by count(*) ) ,
              UserName  = t.UserName ,
              Frequency = count(*)
       from dbo.OrderUser t
       group by t.UserName
     ) summary
where summary.Rank = 1
order by summary.UserName
```

If multiple users share the same lowest frequency, you'll get 1 row back for each such user; otherwise you'll get a single row.

Answer (score 1):

use sql command COUNT to calculate the total number of rows in any table. in your case you will also have to group them by the name of the column you want to calculate the total number for. Here's some access db code, hope you can still read it.

```
SELECT UserName, COUNT (*) As MinMax 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY UserName;
```